# how to run dhrystone after getting dhrystone executable

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, cpu-usage, cpu-cycles

I have compiled dhrystone using the following command gcc dhrystone_1.c dhrystone_2.c -DHZ=60 -o dhrystone and got the executable. Now how do I use the executable (dhrystone) on my code to calculate the number of cpu cycles consumed. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ran the executable. Just copied on SD card which contains the Uboot for the board I am using and ran it to get the Dhrystone per second.